# MRaid : when is ad on screen?

Tags: mraid

from the Mraid specification, I understood that the isViewable function should return whether the ad is currently on screen or not - but looking at different implementations, like in AppNexus demo app (on iphone)- I notices that this value is always true - regardless of whether the ad is on screen or not, and the viewable change event related to this is never fired - not when switching tabs inside the app or when returning to the phone's home screen. 
What's the correct behavior? Is there some other way of knowing whether the ad is rendered on screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the visibility status of webview by overriding onVisibilityChange() method and notify mraid.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is not to rely on marid.isViewable, or viewableChange event of mraid. First correct implementation of these mraid methods is SDK Ad vendor specific and then this doesn't seem to work reliably in different platforms like IOS, Android  or windows. I have precisely experienced same problems. Though most of the Ad SDK vendors seem to support it correctly in IOS.